# Java - dead code in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm getting a dead code warning in a for loop at `i++`. Why do I get that, and how do I solve this problem?

```
public static boolean Method(int p) {
    for(int i = 2; i < p; i++) {  // here is the problem, at i++
        if(p % i == 0);         
            return false;
    }
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: What is the value of p here ?

Comment: You tricked me! That semicolon was hard to see...

Comment: @jmendeth it is always ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
if(p % i == 0);
```

Remove semicolon and try again

Answer (score 13):

You always exit the loop immediately, hence `i` never gets incremented.

```
    if(p % i == 0);         
        return false;
```

should be

```
    if(p % i == 0)       
        return false;
```

In the first version you have an empty clause following the if statement (due to the first semi-colon). Consequently the `return false` always executes. You exit the method, and the `i++` never executes.

Answer (score 7):

Remove the semicolon after your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is expanded then it will become

```
     public static boolean Method(int p) {
        for(int i = 2; i < p; i++) {  // here is the problem, at i++
            if(p % i == 0)
            {

            }
           return false; //If you give return statement here then how it will work.
        }
        return true;    
    }
```